# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x002D2A28 в OpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0000005C

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, opengl, visual-studio-2017

Подскажите ,пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "controls.hpp"
GLFWwindow* window;
                       // Include GLM
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include "controls.hpp"

glm::mat4 ViewMatrix;
glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

glm::mat4 getViewMatrix() {
return ViewMatrix;
}
glm::mat4 getProjectionMatrix() {
return ProjectionMatrix;
}


// Initial position : on +Z
glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0, 0, 5);
// Initial horizontal angle : toward -Z
float horizontalAngle = 3.14f;
// Initial vertical angle : none
float verticalAngle = 0.0f;
// Initial Field of View
float initialFoV = 45.0f;

float speed = 3.0f; // 3 units / second
float mouseSpeed = 0.005f;



void computeMatricesFromInputs() {

// glfwGetTime is called only once, the first time this function is called
static double lastTime = glfwGetTime();

// Compute time difference between current and last frame
double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
float deltaTime = float(currentTime - lastTime);

// Get mouse position
double xpos, ypos;
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);

// Reset mouse position for next frame
glfwSetCursorPos(window, 1024 / 2, 768 / 2);

// Compute new orientation
horizontalAngle += mouseSpeed * float(1024 / 2 - xpos);
verticalAngle += mouseSpeed * float(768 / 2 - ypos);

// Direction : Spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates conversion
glm::vec3 direction(
    cos(verticalAngle) * sin(horizontalAngle),
    sin(verticalAngle),
    cos(verticalAngle) * cos(horizontalAngle)
);

// Right vector
glm::vec3 right = glm::vec3(
    sin(horizontalAngle - 3.14f / 2.0f),
    0,
    cos(horizontalAngle - 3.14f / 2.0f)
);

// Up vector
glm::vec3 up = glm::cross(right, direction);

// Move forward
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_UP) == GLFW_PRESS) {
    position += direction * deltaTime * speed;
}
// Move backward
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_DOWN) == GLFW_PRESS) {
    position -= direction * deltaTime * speed;
}
// Strafe right
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_RIGHT) == GLFW_PRESS) {
    position += right * deltaTime * speed;
}
// Strafe left
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT) == GLFW_PRESS) {
    position -= right * deltaTime * speed;
}

float FoV = initialFoV;// - 5 * glfwGetMouseWheel(); // Now GLFW 3 requires 
setting up a callback for this. It's a bit too complicated for this 
beginner's tutorial, so it's disabled instead.

                       // Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, 
display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(FoV), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 
100.0f);
// Camera matrix
ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
    position,           // Camera is here
    position + direction, // and looks here : at the same position, plus 
"direction"
    up                  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
);

// For the next frame, the "last time" will be "now"
lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

Исключение в этой строке:

```
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Адрес 0x0000005C очень маленький. Попытка обращения к таким адресам чаще всего означает что у вас в коде где-то нулевой указатель.

Конкретно в вашем случае нулевым указателем является window. Вы нигде его не создаете и не заполняете...

Comment: Спасибо! Указатель заполнялся в другом исходнике. Дописал в этом исходнике `extern` и исключение пропало .